# How to add Guake to the Unity top Bar?

Tags: panel, guake

I am using [Guake](http://guake.org/)  in Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit ,is there any way i can put it on the Unity top Panel .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### ubuntu 12.04 - 12.10

To add Guake to the Unity system-tray, you need to add it to the system-whitelist

[image]

Using `dconf-editor` (installed using the `dconf-tools` package), navigate as shown and add `guake` to the whitelist.

You then just start the app via `guake &` to make it appear in the system tray.

Make sure your guake properties (`guake -p`) has the system tray checkbox ticked:

[image]

### 13.10 and later

The ability to whitelist applications has been removed from Unity.

The argument the developers have is that applications should have been updated to support Ubuntu indicators.

There isnt a direct method to-do this without adding an additional PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gun101/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install guake-indicator
```

Search for "Guake indicator" in the dash to start the app-indicator

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.10, I see no 'panel' under 'unity', only 'lenses' and 'runner' =/

Comment: On 12.10 in `dconf` , `systray-whitelist` is accessible at `com > canonical > unity > panel`.

Comment: Any solutions for 14.10?

Comment: @Jorge - see the edit for a suggested solution

Answer (score 0):

You can only put launchers in the Unity launcher panel (left one).

Another idea would be to use the compiz "Commands" plugin and bind guake to the top of the screen. You'll have to click the top of your screen instead of an icon.

Comment: I was trying to avoid compiz altogether, even though F12 is the shortcut for Guake , but since Synapse and Banshee have their Icons on the top panel bar upon installations , i was wondering it was possible without extra tweaks. .Then should it be, that i post this as suggestion to Guake developers for this feature in Unity Desktop. Thanks.